# How to set the location of SWT Dialog?

Tags: eclipse, dialog, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a button. If clicked a Dialog opens up. The Dialog always appears at the center of the screen even though I want to place it to a certain location.

Why is that? How can I set the location of my Dialog?

```java
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        Dialog dialog = new MyDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), "MyDialog");
        dialog.open();
        Point pt = ImageDisplayHelper.getDisplay().getCursorLocation();
        System.out.println("location pt: "+pt); // pt is a valid location something like Point {1368, 220}
        dialog.getShell().setLocation(pt); // no effect whatsoever
        dialog.getShell().setLocation(10, 10); // no effect whatsoever
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog `open` method displays the dialog and waits for it to be closed. So setting the location after calling `open` is too late.

Instead call the `create` method of dialog, then set the location and finally call `open`:

```java
dialog.create();

... set location

dialog.open();
```

An alternative is to override the

```java
protected Point getInitialLocation(Point initialSize)
```

method in the dialog and return the location you want.